# How to copy element of a web page to other web pages using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I know that  I can change the value of a web page using following code in Java script

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
</script>
```

I want to assign a new value for my p tag which get value from another web page other web site

Comment: Are you using common JavaScript file in both web page?

Comment: as long as both pages come from same origin you can simply get it using ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery on your page, you can solve this in one line with the jQuery.load() function like this:

```
$( "#demo" ).load( "yourURL #other-content" );
```

Where `#demo` is the p tag on your page, and `#other-content` is the p tag on the other page. 
More documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Note: for this to work both pages have to be on the same domain.